# Full Squares on the Coordinate Plane

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

This problem has appeared in one of the MBA entrance papers. I know the answer and have seen that it's possible to get an output on Desmos etc. to verify the result. But I am having a hard time figuring out a simple, elegant way to get to the answer, without a graphing tool at my disposal. It goes like,

Rekha drew a circle of radius $2$ cm on a graph paper of grid $1 cm × 1 cm$. She then calculated the area of the circle by adding up only the number of full unit-squares that fell within the perimeter of the circle. If the value that Rekha obtained was $d$ square cm. less than the correct value, then find the minimum possible value of $d$?

The correct answer is $5.56$, and it is so because Rekha can have a maximum of seven squares within her circle. Now I do not know how to prove that, as I said, "manually". I mean, how to fit that circle, beginning with what coordinate for which location, to arrive at seven full squares definitely within Rekha's circle?

A simple explanation without hard geometry, shall be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a square that covers the centre of the circle. Then at most this square and its eight neighbours (forming a $3\times 3$ block) are covered by the circle. Since the diagonal of this block has length $3\sqrt 2>4$, you cannot have *both* the top left and the lower right square covered, nor can you have *both* the top right and lower left square covered. It follows that *at most* seven squares are covered. To see that seven can indeed be achieved, simply let the circle pass through two neighbouring square vertices. For example, the circle passes trough $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ if its centre is at $(\frac12,\sqrt{4-\frac14})=(\frac12,\frac12\sqrt{15})$.

You can check that $(2,3)$ is still inside the circle:
$$ \left(2-\frac12\right)^2+\left(3-\frac12\sqrt{15}\right)^2
=\frac94+9-3\sqrt{15}+\frac{15}4=15-3\sqrt{15}$$
Numerically, this is $\approx 3.38$,  but you can also see that it is $<4$ because that's equivalent to $3\sqrt{15}>11$, or $9\cdot 15>121$.

Likewise, $(2,1)$ is inside the circle:
$$ \left(2-\frac12\right)^2+\left(1-\frac12\sqrt{15}\right)^2
=\frac94+1-\sqrt{15}+\frac{15}4=7-\sqrt{15}$$
which is $<4$ because $\sqrt{15}>3$.

Then by convexity of the cirle, $[-1,2]\times [1,3]$ is covered (=six squares) as well as $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks !! makes sense